# Got to another view controller before the current view controller appears

Tags: ios

I am trying to to go to a new view controller before the current view controller appears but can't seem to get it. Basically my app, starts on a splash page and checks if you have a saved NSUserDefaults and if yes it opens the main view controller. However I don't want a user to see that view before seeing the main view when they are already a user, it's not user friendly. I want the a current user to see the launch image and then the main view directly. However I can't really get that done. This is what I have done which produces the undesired effect.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; NSString *user = [prefs stringForKey:@"userName"];

if(user.length>0){
    NSLog(@"Going straight to main %s", "Yes");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"startMain" sender:self];

  }
}
```

How an I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve what you want, i. e., don't see the first viewController at all, you have to remove the animation in the transition. Without the animation, the user will see as the secondViewController was the first presented.

You can achieve this in many ways. One of them (assuming it's a modal), would be creating a new segue in the storyboard, with a different identifier and no animation, and calling it if your condition is true.

It would be something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; NSString *user = [prefs stringForKey:@"userName"];

    if(user.length>0){
        NSLog(@"Going straight to main %s", "Yes");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"startMain-noAnimation" sender:self];
      }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this in viewDidLoad -- you'll get an error saying you're trying to present a view controller while another presentation is in progress. You have to leave it in viewDidAppear, but with no animation like you said.

Comment: That's awkward, because I have a project that presents a modal login screen inside `viewDidLoad` (through `presentViewController:animated:completion:`). My controller is inside a tabBarController, I don't know if this has something to do

Comment: Are you sure you did it in viewDidLoad? I just tested this on a controller that is in the first tab of a tab bar controller, and I got the error: "Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0x9159f70> on <UITabBarController: 0x9151cd0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!". I get the same error if I try it in viewWillAppear.

Comment: My controller is the third tab. I will check with debug when got in home

Comment: I checked that situation, and it does indeed work if you're not doing it from the controller in the first tab -- that makes sense, because the error is saying that it's the tab bar controller itself that's not in the window hierarchy, and of course it will be by the time you select a different tab after launch. However, I don't think this will be useful for the OP's situation.

Comment: Its working fine if I try to do same in viewWillAppear. I am not seeing any error mention by @rdelmar

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it using the appdelegate and storyboard ids. Here's what I did.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //Check to see if this is a current user or a new user
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; NSString *user = [prefs stringForKey:@"userName"];

    //Current User
    if(user.length>0){
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"2"];

        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    } else {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"1"];

        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try this in your appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; NSString *user = [prefs stringForKey:@"userName"];
    if(user.length>0){
        NSLog(@"Going straight to main %s", "Yes");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"startMain" sender:self];

    } else {
        self.window.rootViewController = splashScreenViewController;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help man. I'm trying your code and it doesn't seem as the appdelegate knows the method performSegueWithIdentifier. I assume it's a method under the viewcontroller hierarchy.